# redirect subdomain pages to a primary domain page

Tags: redirect, iis-10

I have a client need to redirect URL's like this:

https://events.example.com/page/

to a specific page on the main domain:

https://www.example.com/events

and I'm not having any luck doing this. The DNS changes have been made, so the main events.example.com points at the home page currently and I'm trying to use IIS rewrite rules in Azure web.config to accomplish this. Not sure if it matters, but the site is hosted on Sitecore 8.2.7. Here is the rule that I have to this point:

```
<rule name="Events Sub-domain Redirect">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="events.example.com^" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="www.example.com/page-target" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
```

I have tried several variations of this w/ no luck whatsoever. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want redirect from `https://events.example.com/page` to `https://www.example.com/events`, you can refer to this example:

```
<rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^events.example.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/page" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/events" />
</rule>
```